# Two same name variables

Tags: javascript, variables

In https://github.com/Khan/khan-exercises/blob/master/khan-exercise.js

there are two `var Khan` variables. How come? Do they affect each other?

Comment: It'd be nice if you added excerpts of the relevant parts

Comment: gave a quick check at the code, seems to me that the khan named function (first declaration of var kahn) contains an object named khan... i don't think there's a clash in that, since they're in different scopes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One `Khan` is the name of the global variable "`Khan`", the other is a variable inside the self executing function that it is equal to.

```
var Khan = (function(){

    ....

    var Khan = ...

    ....

})();
```

The indentation in the source file is horrible and you probably did not notice that....

Comment: In my opinion, this is bad coding style to redefine the same name in the same scope for different purposes as it can clearly lead to confusion and there is no coding benefit versus picking a different name for one of them.

Answer (score 2):

variables wrapped in anonymous functions only work inside that function.

So this should work okay.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   var khan = (function(){
        var khan = //this should not be a problem and they both work, this will be only available in the function
   }); 
});
</script>
```